# How to send the Assignment Email with a link to the task in it SharePoint 2013 Visual Studio Workflow

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have developed a Visual Studio 2012 workflow for SharePoint 2013.

I am trying to find a way to simply send a link to the actual Task in the Assignment email. I have created a variable and set the "TaskItemId" in the output sections of the properties to that variable.

I then reference my variable in the body of the AssignmentEmailBody property. When the email gets sent the TaskID is null. In sharepoint designer there is a "Start Task Initation Process". I am guessing it creates the task first, returns the ID and then moves on to everything else.

Does anyone have ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

simple way!

< a href='%TaskSpecial: TaskUrl%'>%Task: Title% < /a>