# SharePoint 2013 Visual Studio workflow, add variables to task email html markup

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-2013

I couldn't find any documentation on this.

I found this posting over here: [How to send the Assignment Email with a link to the task in it SharePoint 2013 Visual Studio Workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391795/how-to-send-the-assignment-email-with-a-link-to-the-task-in-it-sharepoint-2013-v)

The questions is

1. **Where can I find some piece of documentation on the tokens available out of the box?**
2. **How can I use my own variables here? %myvariable% didn't work..**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]If i understand you properly, you can create your global variable in the workflow and use that variable in your email text.

Comment: How exactly? I do have variables - how do I make them appear in the email body? All I (literally) get is %myVariable% instead of its value.

Comment: OMG.. I'm feeling really stupid right now. Probably I was blinded by the designer's rich html editing experience where as in VS you have indeed a plain text html string.